# Show popup in markdown after '@' sign to search for users

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, tui

I'm trying to recreate functionality from Gitlab to show users list after writing '@' sign.

Currently I'm trying to add it to Tui Editor (using Vue).

I know how to listen for key up and add it as Widget, but it has a few drawbacks.

```
editor.on('keyup', (editorType, ev) => {

 if (ev.key === '@') {
   const userMenu = this.$refs.userMenu;
   refEditor.addWidget(userMenu.$el, 'top');
 }
});
```

1. After writing anything after '@' popup disappears.
2. When I write something like '@an' and delete 'an' it's not showing popup again.
3. When I lose focus from markdown and then focus it again and the caret is right after @ sign it isn't showing popup.

At this point I'm not sure where I should start.

So it should work this way: writing '@' should show me popup and when I write letters it should filter users according to those letters. It should make popup window visible whenever @ is at the start of a word, so '@@' or 'f@' shouldn't work.

Using: ES6+, Vue 2, Tui Editor, Vuetify.

Answer (score 0):

so the logic should be the following:

1. user types input, and we use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html?redirect=true) to attach it to a data object. and we want to initiate a data variable `isTag` to false
2. we want to listen to every word until we hear '@', so basically, we want to listen to the first click when input data is empty
3. if we hear '@', we set `isTag` to true
4. now, using `v-if`, we can open our modal conditionally and listen using the `v-model` to the typing data as it changes.

I don't know `tui-editor`, so I can only help you with `vue` code; it would be something like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/GuyNachshon/fxo0nu2e/10/) (jsfiddle)